# Verify divergence theorem (Integral Boundaries)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

I am not sure how to get the boundaries for this problem. So far, I have worked out $\mathbf{n}=\nabla(1-r^2-z)=-(2r\mathbf{e}_r-\mathbf{e}_z)$, normalize it so $$\hat{\mathbf{n}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(2r\mathbf{e}_r-\mathbf{e}_z).$$

I think the area element is $dA=rdrd\theta$ and volume element $dV=rdrd\theta dz$ and $$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}=\frac{z}{r}.$$

So, I have $$\int_V 1-r^2 drd\theta dz=\int_S -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}drd\theta.$$

But I don't know how to find the boundaries for this problem. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$d\mathbf S = \nabla (z - 1 + r^2) dx dy =
(2r \mathbf e_r + z \mathbf e_z) dx dy, \\
z \mathbf e_r \cdot d\mathbf S = 2 r z \,dx dy = 2 r^2 z \,dr d\theta,$$
where $\mathbf e_r$ and $\mathbf e_z$ are associated with cylindrical coordinates. It remains to verify that
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{2 \pi} 2 r^2 z \bigg\rvert_{z = 1 - r^2} d\theta dr =
\int_0^1 \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{1 - r^2} \frac z r r \,dz d\theta dr.$$

Comment: How did you get the integral boundaries? Why do you change the order of $drd\theta$ and $drd\theta dz$?

Comment: The base is a disk of radius $1$, specified in polar coordinates $r, \theta$. The surface is defined by taking $z = 1 - r^2$ for each point $(r, \theta)$. For the solid, we take values of $z$ between $0$ and $1 - r^2$. Therefore we have to integrate wrt $z$ first.

Comment: Why do we have to take values of $z$ between $0$ and $1-r^2$? Sorry for my multiple questions, I just want to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: The first integral is a surface integral. The second integral is a volume integral. Intuitively, since we're summing infinitesimal volumes in the second integral, we have to go over the vicinity of every point inside the solid. It's exactly the same thing as taking a [volume integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_integral) over a cube. Is your question about the shape of the solid?

Comment: I think I understand better now. No, my question was about the process of figuring out the boundaries of $r,\theta,z$ for both integrals.